# Extension of a biholomorphic function on annulus

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:C_r \rightarrow C_s$ be a biholomorphic function where $C_t := \{1 < |z| < t \} $. How to extend $f: \overline{C_r} \rightarrow \overline{C_s}$ such that it is continuous and bijective?

My attempt was to try to express $f$ as a laurent series at $z=0$ but the idea was sadly not fruitful.

Comment: @user8675309 you are right, fixed.

Comment: Sketch; bijectivity and open mapping show that if $z$ goes to a boundary circle, then $f(z)$ goes to a boundary circle which is same for the same original boundary circle; also each original circle goes to a distinct circle; using a biholomorphic inversion that swaps the boundary circles on the image, we can assume wlog $|f(z)| \to 1, |z| \to 1$ and $|f(z)| \to s, |z|\to r$; then $\log |f|- \log s\log |z|/\log r$ is harmonic on the original annulus continuous and zero on the boundary, so is identically zero; hence $|f|=|z|^c$; by analyticity and bijectivity $c=1, s=r$ and $f$ is a rotation

Comment: In general remembering the possibility that we have to compose with an inversion, $f$ is either a rotation or a rotation composed with an inversion

Comment: @Conrad Could you elaborate your solution? I'm confused with the boundary circles etc. What does open mapping have to do with how the boundary circles behave?

Comment: @Conrad it would be great if you'd write an answer because I'd like to understand your solution more, thanks